# How can I send a copy of a PHP / HTML form to the sender's email address?

Tags: php, html, forms, email, checkbox

I have a checkbox that confirms if the sender wants the copy of the form to his/her email. Now, how can I have get it to work with PHP?

I have the following HTML form code. "sendcopy checkbox" shows the bottom of this code:

```
<form id="contact-form" action="send_form.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="recipient" value="myemail@domain.net">

    <input type="hidden" name="inhtml" value="yes">
    <div class="contact-row">
        <div style="float: left; width: 34%;">
            <input class="contact-input"  style="width: 300px;"  name="name" placeholder="Name*" required><br>
        </div>
        <div style="float: left; width: 33%;">
            <input class="contact-input"  style="width: 290px;" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="email"><br>
        </div>
        <div style="float: right; width: 33%;">
            <input class="contact-input" style="width: 305px;" name="subject" placeholder="Subject*" required><br>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="contact-row">
        <textarea cols="173" rows="10" name="message" placeholder="Message*" required></textarea><br>
    </div>
    <br>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="sendcopy" value="Yes" checked/>Send copy to your mail
    </label>
    <br>
    <div class="confirm">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="confirm" required>
            Confirm that you are people.
        </label>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="contact-row">
        <div class="contact-row">
            <center>
                <input id="contact-submit" type="image" src="submit.png" alt="Send" />
            </center>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And my PHP code:

```js
<?php
    $recipient = $_POST["recipient"];
    $subject = $_POST["subject"];
    $inhtml = $_POST["inhtml"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $message = $_POST["message"];
    $sendCopy = isset($_POST['sendcopy'];
    $charset = 'utf-8';
    $head =
        "From: $email \r\n" .
        "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" .
        "Content-Type: text/html; charset=$charset\r\n" .
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit";
    $body = '';
    if ($inhtml == 'yes') {
        $body = '<html><body style="font-family: Arial; color: #727272;">';
        $body = $body . '<h3 style="font-size: 16px;">Name: ' . $name . '</h3>';
        $body = $body . '<h4 style="font-size: 14px;">Subject: ' . $subject . ' (' . $email . ') </h4>';
        $body = $body . '<p style="font-size: 13px;">' . $message . '</p>';
        $body = $body . '</body></html>';
    }
    else {
        $body = $body . 'Name: ' . $name . '
                Subject: ' . $name . ' (' . $email . ')
                Message:
                ' . $message;
    }
    if (mail($recipient, "=?$charset?B?" . base64_encode($subject) . "?=", $body, $head)) {
        if ($sendCopy) {
            $sentToSender = mail($email, "=?$charset?B?" . base64_encode($subject) . "?=", $body, $head);
        }
        header("Location: ../form-success.htm");
        exit;
    }
    else {
        header("Location: ../form-error.htm");
        exit;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Solve what? You haven't explained a problem, only told us the requirements. Show us your attempt to use the checkbox and tell us what's wrong with your code when you try it

Comment: Not part of the described problem, but the start of the body text for the email may not be as intended (probably there shouldn't be any leading spaces in the beginning of it and/or it may miss some linebreaks).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, check if the "sendcopy" checkbox is checked:

```
$sendCopy = isset($_POST['sendcopy']);
```

You don't have to check its value. The frontend simply won't send anything if the checkbox is not checked, so if it exists in the $_POST array, that means the user has checked it.

Next, just send the exact same mail to the sender's email address:

```
        if ($sendCopy) {
            $sentToSender = mail($email, "=?$charset?B?" . base64_encode($subject) . "?=", $body, $head);
        }
```

You can add this code just before redirecting your user to the success page.

**The missing parentheses have now been added to the code above, so it works well.**

Comment: I get error message "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ',' or ')' on line 10". Watch my question PHP code, here is how I tried. It refers to "$sendCopy = isset($_POST['sendcopy'];" so there is some character problems.

Comment: You're missing the closing parenthesis on isset. It should be isset($_POST['sendcopy'])

Comment: It works now. Thanks a lot ! I did not noticed the missing parenthesis.