# How can I send a copy of an HTML form to the sender's email using a text box?

Tags: php, html, forms, email, send

My code is same as here: *[How to send copy of PHP / HTML form to sender's email?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63329728/how-to-send-copy-of-php-html-form-to-senders-email)*

I would want that when I write email address to text box then I will get copy of the form to email I wrote.

I have replaced HTML code:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="sendcopy" value="Yes" checked/>Send copy to your mail</label>
```

to

```
<label><b>Write your email here:</b><div style="width: 33%;"><input class="contact-input"style="width: 500px;" name="sendcopy"><br/></div></label>
```

I have replaced PHP code:

```
$sendCopy = isset($_POST['sendcopy']);
```

to

```
$sendCopy = $_POST["sendcopy"];
```

And I replaced PHP code:

```
if ($sendCopy) {
    $sentToSender = mail($email, "=?$charset?B?" . base64_encode($subject) . "?=", $body, $head);}
```

to

```
if (mail($sendCopy, "=?$charset?B?" . base64_encode($subject) . "?=", $body, $head))
```

Now when I write email address to text box, I will get the copy of the form to email I wrote, but when I leave the text box to blank the submission of the form ends with an error.

So, the main thing is that when form sender writes his/her email to a text box he/she will get the copy of the form to his/her email. And when you leave the text box blank, the form will send only to recipient email. How can I do this?

Comment: *"I have replaced PHP code:

$sendCopy = isset($_POST['sendcopy']);"* - Which I told you already will return boolean. That isn't how to use that.

Answer (score -1):

> I have replaced PHP code:
>
> ```
> $sendCopy = isset($_POST['sendcopy']);
> ```

That will always be considered as being "set" and will return a Boolean.

> And when you leave the text box blank, the form will send only to recipient email. How can I do this?

You're looking to use a [ternary operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

From the manual:

> // Example usage for: Ternary Operator
> $action = (empty($_POST['action'])) ? 'default' : $_POST['action'];

So your attempt would round off to:

```
$action = (isset($_POST['sendcopy'])) ? 'default' : $_POST['sendcopy'];
```

While replacing `default` to what you want it to be as a default.

Side note: `isset()` in this instance is good for radios buttons and checkboxes. If you don't want empty fields, you could use `empty()` for text inputs, etc. besides radios buttons and checkboxes.

Comment: Thanks for answer ! I am sorry, I am beginner with Stackoverflow and when I saw that my question is closed,  I did not know that I can answer for you. I solved my code problems with checkbox and jquery, email box comes when I am checked the checkbox. But in the future I know that I can answer to comment although my question is closed. Good coding moments for you and thanks for help !