# Can I submit a PHP form within Cordova?

Tags: php, android, html, forms, cordova

I would need help with Apache Cordova.
I would like to submit a PHP $ POST form within Cordova.

I am tried this one, but when I send it, it goes to separate browser: [Using php form inside phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12711074/using-php-form-inside-phonegap).

My PHP / HTML code is largely similar than that one: [How to send copy of PHP / HTML form to sender's email?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63329728/14276740)

So, main thing would be that I can send the form inside the Cordova app and when I send the form, I do not need to go to separate browser but the transmission takes place inside the app.

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my problem to solved, so I answer for my own question.

I used iframe to the form, that was already on the server. And then I can send PHP form inside Cordova app.